# redirect to login from specific page then return to this page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I  searched on the net and on stackoverflow but I did not find what I am looking for here is my case

I want to redirect users who want to access a specific page to the login url and then redirect them to the previous page
i used this

```
 <?phpif ( is_user_logged_in() || ! is_page() ) return;

$restricted = array( 5049 ); // all your restricted pages

if ( in_array( get_queried_object_id(), $restricted ) ) {
  $previous_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? : site_url( '/user-account' );
  wp_redirect( $previous_url); 
  exit();
  
}});
```

the first part worked well I was redirected to the login page, but it did not subsequently redirect to the old page

I would like to know how I could redirect to the page the user wanted to visit after successful login

Comment: Instead of redirecting to a URL you determine manually, you should use `wp_login_url` - that one takes the URL you want to redirect the user back to _after_ successful login, as the first parameter.

Comment: I did not do this because the user is redirected to the wordpress login page that I would like to hide and replace with that of the theme

Comment: Well then you will have to go and check whether your theme's own login form even provides that kind of functionality to begin with.

Comment: yes i tried and i succefully redirect to login page, then i m looking for a way to redirect to the previous page

Answer (score 0):

Make your own login page with redirect parameter:

```
<?php 
   //get current page ID
   $id = get_queried_object_id();

   $args = array(
       'echo'           => false,
       'redirect'       => get_page_link($id), 
       'form_id'        => 'loginform',
       'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
       'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
       'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
       'label_log_in'   => __( 'Sign In' ),
       'id_username'    => 'user_login',
       'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
       'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
       'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
       'remember'       => true,
       'value_username' => NULL,
       'value_remember' => true
   ); 
        
   // Calling the login form.
   $form = wp_login_form( $args );

   //Display form
   echo $form;
?>
```